# php login mysql query reloads login page (MAMP)

Tags: php, sql

I have read most solutions to this where in logging in keeps reloading the login page, but it still doesn't work for me. I tried logging in different browsers (sadly there's only safari and firefox here). There are no errors even if I type no username or password although there is an errorStr in the codes which prints out errors. It just keeps reloading no matter what.

I am a beginner at php programming and I am trying to access an old php website.

Here is the myfunctions.php where in the sql server is connected.

```
class mysql_db
{

    function openCityPassSQL()
{
        $dbhostname="localhost:8889";
        $dbusername="root";
        $dbpassword="root";         
                    $dbname="ticketing";


        MYSQL_CONNECT($dbhostname,$dbusername,$dbpassword) OR DIE("Unable to connect to database...");
        @mysql_select_db("$dbname") or die("Unable to select database..."); }

    function executeQuery($query)
    {
        return MYSQL_QUERY($query);
    }

    function executeUpdate($query)
    {
        return MYSQL_QUERY($query);
    }

    function numRows($result)
    {
        return MYSQL_NUM_ROWS($result);
    }

    function fetchRow($result)
    {
        return mysql_fetch_array($result);
    }

    function closeSQL()
    {
        MYSQL_CLOSE();
    }
}
```

here is my index.php

```
<?
ini_set('display_errors','1');

$found_msisdn = false;

$temp = $HTTP_COOKIE_VARS["User-Identity-Forward-msisdn"];

if (($temp != null) && ($temp != "")) {
$len = strlen($temp);
$msisdn = "+";
for ($i=0;$i<$len;$i++) {
    if (($i % 2) == 1)
        $msisdn = $msisdn . $temp[$i];
}

$found_msisdn = true;
}     

if (!$found_msisdn) {
//get SMART's MSISDN
$network    = $HTTP_SERVER_VARS["HTTP_X_NETWORK_INFO"];

//GPRS,639218025160,515031808225161,10.155.9.87,unsecured

$info   = explode(",", $network);
$msisdn = $info[1];

if (($msisdn != null) && ($msisdn != "")) {
    $msisdn = "+" . $msisdn;
    $found_msisdn = true;
}
}

if ($found_msisdn) {
$msisdn = urlencode($msisdn);
}

if (preg_match("/vnd.wap.wml/",$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'])){ 
header("Location: http://wap.surfshop.net.ph/citypass/index.wml?msisdn=$msisdn"); 
exit; 
} 


require ("myfunctions.php");
session_start();
$_showform=true;

$errorStr="";
$_username="";
$_password="";

$conn=new mysql_db();
$conn->openCityPassSQL();

if (isSet($a_exit) && $a_exit=="1") 
{
session_unregister("verified_user");
$_showform=false;
header("Location: index.php");
}

if (isSet($submitform))
{
$_username=$username;
$_password=$password;

//if (!nameIsValid($_username)) $errorStr=$errorStr.($errorStr!=""?"<br>":"")."Invalid User ID.";
//if (empty($_password) || !passwordIsValid($_password)) $errorStr=$errorStr.($errorStr!=""?"<br>":"")."Invalid Password.";

if (empty($_username)) {
    $errorStr = "Invalid username<br>";
}
if (empty($_password)) {
    $errorStr .= "Invalid password<br>";
}
if (empty($errorStr))
{
    $tid = 0;

    $query="SELECT Password, PASSWORD('$password') FROM tblUser WHERE UserID='$_username'";
    //echo "query:$query<br>";
    $result=$conn->executeQuery($query);
    $numRows=$conn->numRows($result);

    if ($result && $numRows>0) {
        $RS=mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $pass1=$RS[0];
        $pass2=$RS[1];
        if ($pass1 == $pass2) {
            $query = "SELECT EstabID FROM tblEstabUser WHERE UserID='$_username'";
            $result=$conn->executeQuery($query);
            $RS=mysql_fetch_array($result);
            $tid = $RS[0];

            $admin = false;
            $query = "SELECT UserID FROM tblAdminUser WHERE UserID='$_username'";
            //echo "query:$query<br>";
            $result=$conn->executeQuery($query);
            $numRows=$conn->numRows($result);
            if ($numRows > 0) {
                $admin = true;
                $tid = $numRows[1];             //initialize to a value for links to work
            }

            $verified_user = array($_username, $tid, ($admin?"1":"0"));
            session_register("verified_user");

            $errorStr = "Welcome $_username!<br>";  
            $_showform = false;
            header("Location: index2.php");
        }
        else {
            $errorStr = "Invalid username/password (PA)<br>";
        }
            }
    else {
        $errorStr = "Invalid username/password (NR)<br>";
    }
}
}
```

index2.php

```
session_start();
$_showform=true;
if (!session_is_registered("verified_user"))
{
    $_showform=false;
    header("Location: index.php");
}
else
{    
list($username,$estabid,$admin)=$verified_user;
if (empty($username))
{
    $_showform=false;
    header("Location: index.php");
}

}

if ($_showform)
{
?>
<html>
<head>
<title><?=$applicationName?></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" text="#000000" topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">

<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
  <td>
<?include("header.php");?>
  </td>
</tr>

<?
    //if ($errorStr!="")
    if ($username!="")
    {
?>
            <tr>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><font face="Verdana" size="2">&nbsp;</font></td>
            </tr>
<?
    }
?>


<tr>
  <td>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>

        <td valign="top">
<?include("menu_in.php");?>
        </td>

        <td valign="top">
           <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

             <tr>
               <td>
               </td>
             </tr>

           </table>
        </td>


          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </table>
</body>
</html>

<?
}
?>
```

I don't really know what the error is, but my guess is the script is just old and my MAMP can't process the query?
I'm just an intern and any help would be appreciated.

These are the following errors I have encountered:

> Notice: Undefined index: User-Identity-Forward-msisdn in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ticketing/index.php on line 6
>
> Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_X_NETWORK_INFO in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ticketing/index.php on line 21
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ticketing/index.php on line 26
>
> Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session
>   cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ticketing/index.php:6) in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ticketing/index.php on line 45

Comment: Please put ini_set('display_errors','1'); o the top of your php file to turn the error reporting which may helpful for find out the error.

Comment: I have edited my index.php codes and received the errors. But I still don't understand what's wrong?

Comment: I added ob_start(); at the top of index.php and it solve my session_start() error. 3 errors remaining, anyone can suggest anything why i can't seem to login and why my errorStr isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

The error information which you have provided clearly shows that

```
$HTTP_COOKIE_VARS["User-Identity-Forward-msisdn"];
$HTTP_SERVER_VARS["HTTP_X_NETWORK_INFO"];
```

are completely empty.

Please use

```
print_r($HTTP_COOKIE_VARS);
print_r($HTTP_SERVER_VARS);
```

to check for whether the values exists or not.
If there are values in these arrays then your third problem

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ticketing/index.php on line 26
```

will be solved automatically.

Comment: Thank you. I have edited that part and this showed in my index.php page. 
`Array ( [SQLiteManager_currentLangue] => 2 [PHPSESSID] => 72d74e1b38c7401264c1acb4ef64fe88 )`

Comment: I get a different Array when I use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost, is this significant? `Array ( [PHPSESSID] => 8474b95d6ed724a21e6f164716622acf )`

Comment: No that's not relevant ..............My friend you did not got the point.....The array $HTTP_COOKIE_VARS["User-Identity-Forward-msisdn"] and $HTTP_SERVER_VARS["HTTP_X_NETWORK_INFO"];
are empty.....You need to find the correct place to get your desired values......

Answer (score 0):

on which page it redirects do you know?

Note: SELECT UserID FROM tblAdminUser WHERE UserID='$_username' (i know its not relevant but is USERID col belongs to username?)

Comment: It redirects me to the same page, index.php. Yes my UserID column is my source for username. Whether my username and password is right or wrong it does the same thing which refreshes the same page.

Comment: try to block all headers and test it if this problem still exist then let me know

Comment: I have posted all the needed php files to run the login page. I am using MAMP and connected my sql there. However I cannot post the sql here from the field names ing queries it is easy to guess what is needed.